# Xcode 4.3.2 - missing iOS controls

Tags: xcode, ios5

I think I'm missing some controls in the tool window in Xcode 4.3.2.

I created a new iOS 5 project, and my list of controls looks like this:

[image: Xcode 4.3.2 controls list]

I noticed that I got more controls when I opened a sample project downloaded from the Apple dev site.

Then I tried to open my own project, which started out showing a code file. Then I got a huge list. But as soon as I view the storyboard, or a Xib file it reverts back to the shorter list.

In the huge list of controls, some of them doesn't look iOS-ish. I suspect that it loads the whole lot Xcode has to offer across project types (both iOS, Mac). Looks like this:

[image: Huge controls list]

Do I need to manually load some frameworks, or similar into my project in order to get more controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first screenshot shows the CocoaTouch controls, the second one shows standard Cocoa Controls. Not all of the latter ones are available on iOS/CocoaTouch. You can change the filter with the drop-down menu directly above the list ("Objects" in the first screenshot, "Object Library" in the second one)

Comment: Alright. Thought it looked odd. Some of the descriptions said mouse events and stuff, which sounded wrong for ios.